# How can I wrap an Ascii value back to "A" if it's gone past "Z", without using If statements?

Tags: java

I can't figure out a proper solution without using an If Statement. My assignment explicitly says I cannot use an If Statement, so I am currently at a standstill.

Comment: It's hard to believe that this wasn't covered in your class before the assignment was set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer your question exactly, but point you to the concept...

Most languages offer a modulus operator. (%) This is the equivalent of doing a division, but instead of returning the quotient, it returns you the remainder.

```
int n = 26%12;   // 26 divided by 12 = 2 remainder 4. n = 4
```

One use for the modulus operator is to efficiently do a wrap around. For example, if you wanted to print out the numbers 1 to 7 repeatedly...

```
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Console.log(n+1); 
    n = (n+1)%7;
}
```

This would output

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
1
2
3